# How can i use jsonfield in F expression?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-jsonfield

i  have jsonfield in model,and i want to run this query:

```
Notification.objects.filter(Q(data__payload__request_visit_time__gte=(timezone.now() - timedelta(minutes=1) * ((1 + F("data__payload__visit_duration_plan")) * 15)).isoformat()))
```

but jsonfield do not work in F expression.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will be possible using `F` expression. As a workaround, you can first add a dynamic field using annotate and then apply conditions using that.

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

Notification.objects.annotate(
visit_duration = RawSQL("(data -> payload ->> visit_duration_plan)::int")
).filter(Q(
    data__payload__request_visit_time__gte=(
            timezone.now() - timedelta(minutes=1) * ((1 +  F("visit_duration")) * 15)).isoformat()))
```